# Setlocale function for strptime - locale strings I would love to know

Tags: php, locale

I would like to use `setlocale` function to set locale for my function before use of `strptime` to get the time in a post request.

But I am  using  an old PHP version (5.1) which results in a runtime error reporting that this function is not defined. For example:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'id_ID.UTF8', 'id_ID.UTF-8', 'id_ID.8859-1', 'id_ID', 'IND.UTF8', 
          'IND.UTF-8', 'IND.8859-1', 'IND', 'Indonesian.UTF8', 'Indonesian.UTF-8', 
          'Indonesian.8859-1', 'Indonesian', 'Indonesia', 'id', 'ID', 'en_US.UTF8', 
          'en_US.UTF-8', 'en_US.8859-1', 'en_US', 'American', 'ENG', 'English');
```

I would like to know where those locale strings are defined? I don't know where people take them from to fill in such a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get default locale for language in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568762/get-default-locale-for-language-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

On the computer where you execute your PHP scripts, execute the following system command:

```
locale -a
```

It will return the installed locales.

See as well the *[locale(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locale)* and a related (if not duplicate) question:

- [Get default locale for language in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568762/get-default-locale-for-language-in-php)
- [List of available collators in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9422553/367456)