# PHP: Where does setlocale's Value Come From?

Tags: php, locale

I've noticed that PHP's [`str_word_count`](https://www.php.net/str_word_count) is behaving differently on the command line vs. on the web.  The behavior *seems* to due to the default locale value in each environment.  If I use [setlocale](https://www.php.net/setlocale) to view the current locale (`echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);`), on the command line I get

```
C/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/C/C
```

Whereas on the web I get

```
C
```

So where do the various PHP SAPIs (cli, fpm, mod_php, etc.) get this default value from?

My presumption is that the weird looking `C/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/C/C` locale all six locale categories jammed up together, and that this is telling me `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` and the other categories are all set the `C` locale -- so putting my question another way: Why is does my php-fpm server have all its locale categories set to `C` by default, whereas my command line PHP has one locale set to `en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that PHP is picking these values up *directly* from the shell's environment, and that the value for `LC_CTYPE` will also check `LANG`'s value

```
% cat test.php
<?php
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0),"\n";

% echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8

% echo $LC_CTYPE

% php test.php
C/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/C/C

% LC_CTYPE=C php test.php
C

% LANG=C php test.php
C

% LANG=C LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 php test.php
C/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/C/C
```

So, MacOS appears to set LANG to `en_US.UTF-8` for a user's personal shell.  My presumption is when I'm starting my php-fpm instance via

```
brew services start php
```

that the -- LaunchAgent? -- is using a shell where `LANG` or `LC_CTYPE` is set to `C` -- presumably because only humans are interesting in seeing things formatted as UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

**I assume that with "on the web" you refer to Apache web server under Linux ...**

In this case the reason for `setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)` returning `C` is as follows:

If you check `/etc/apache2/envvars` from your Apache server you will find the following lines:

```
## The locale used by some modules like mod_dav
export LANG=C
## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
#. /etc/default/locale
```

As e result a `phpinfo()` will produce the following output:

[image: Apache Environment with LANG=C]

If you modify the lines in `/etc/apache2/envvars` as follows ...

```
## The locale used by some modules like mod_dav
# export LANG=C
## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
. /etc/default/locale
```

and restart Apache. Then Apache will use the locale and language settings from your operating system(you can check them os settings with the `locale` command in a terminal). As a result from the change above a `phpinfo()` will produce for example the following output on a system with `de_CH.UTF-8` locale defined:

[image: Apache Environment vars with LANG=de_CH.UTF-8]

**But you may still end up having `setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)` returning `C` or at least some of the `LC_` variables being set to `C`** e.g `LC_CTYPE=de_CH.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"`

In order to ensure that PHP uses the locale settings from the OS you have to call `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")`.
The manual of `setlocale` under https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php states the following:

```
// If locales is the empty string "", the locale names will be set from 
// the values of environment variables with the same names as the above
// categories, or from "LANG".

// On Windows, setlocale(LC_ALL, '') sets the locale names from the 
// system's regional/language settings (accessible via Control Panel).
```

**And finally your `setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)` returns the value(s) configured on your operating system e.g. `de_CH.UTF-8` :-)**

Answer (score 1):

You can set [intl.default_locale](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.configuration.php) in php.ini

Comment: +1 for useful info -- but it doesn't seem to answer my question.  The value is `intl.default_locale => no value => no value` on both my php command line, as well as my web server. Also -- I'm not 100% sure that `intl.default_locale` controls the same sort of things that setlocale does.

Comment: _nod_ per this answer, the intl locale is a different thing from the old C locales and controls different things. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45828833/4668